# Style sheet positioning won't keep everything in place

Tags: css-position

I'm hoping this will link to my bin - http://jsbin.com/vuqaw/1/edit

The problem I'm having is that I'm a newb as the user name states.  Either way.  I'm trying to layout my personal blog with a 2 column layout.  I'm doing it all in hopes that when a window is resized smaller the content will stay the same size AND stay put.  If possible, I'd like the 2 columns to be nearly bumped up next to one another.

In my search I've found some other interesting helpful things (Google links directly back to SO for most searches), but this is where I hit the brickwall.  (I'm probably nowhere near searching for the correct terms

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove absolute positioning and float both containers to the left. Try these:

```
#navright{
  width:20%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 15px 175px 0px 0px;
  padding:15px;
  float:left;
}

#blogcontentleft{  
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 185px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's the solution until I get thrown for another loop.